# C++: program has stopped working

Tags: c++

I am trying to write a simple program. Given the position of a queen on a chess board the program should display all the possible blocks at which it can attack. Here is the code.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void mark(int x, int y, char bd[][8]);  
void display(char bd[][8]);     
void init (char bd[][8]);       

int main()
{
    char b[8][8];       
    int r,c;        //variable to store row and column
    init (b);       //initially marking every position with '*'
    cout << "Enter the posotion of the queen:" << endl;
    cout << "Row: ";
    cin >> r;
    cout << "Column: ";
    cin >> c;
    mark(r,c,b);        //function to mark the attackable places
    display(b);         //function to display the output
    cin.get();           
}

void mark(int x, int y, char bd[][8])
{
    bd[x][y] = 'x';     //marking queen's position
    int i,j;

    //marking vertical line. '-' represent a attackable position 
    for (i=0; i<8; i++)
    {
        if(i != x)      
            bd[i][y] = '-';     
    }

    //marking horizontal line
    for (j=0; j<8; j++)
    {
        if(j != y)
            bd[x][j] = '-';     
    }

    //forward diagonal
    i = x+1;
    j = y+1;
    while(i != 8 || j != 8)
    {
        bd[i][j] = '-';
        i++;
        j++;
    }

    i = x-1;
    j = y-1;
    while(i != -1 || j != -1)
    {
        bd[i][j] = '-';
        i--;
        j--;
    }

    //backward diagonal
    i = x+1;
    j = y-1;
    while(i != 8 || j != -1)
    {
        bd[i][j] = '-';
        i++;
        j--;
    }

    i = x-1;
    j = y+1;
    while(i != -1 || j != 8)
    {
        bd[i][j] = '-';
        i--;
        j++;
    }

    return;

}

void display(char bd[][8])
{
    for(int i=0; i<8; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<8; j++)
            cout << bd[i][j];
        cout << endl;
    }
}

void init (char bd[][8])
{
    for(int i=0; i<8; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<8; j++)
            bd[i][j] = '*';
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

It should generate an output like:

```
Enter the posotion of the queen:
Row: 1
Column: 1
---*****
-x------
---*****
*-*-****
*-**-***
*-***-**
*-****-*
*-*****-
```

But when I run it I get a message saying 'program has stopped working. Windows can check online for a solution to the problem.' If I comment out the part under backward diagonal then the code runs fine. And there are no building errors. I cannot understand what's the problem. Is it going in an infinite loop? Can someone please help?

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info (`g++ -Wall -Wextra -g` if using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...) then **use the debugger** (`gdb`)

Comment: Why you don't run it in debug mode ? then you can check step-by-step what's going wrong .

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch She is mentioning that she is using windows. You are also right, this can be compiled with g++ on Linux, and there is a segfault with the array bd in mark(), because of improper array value check. Just giving support to new users to not get downvoted as much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `mark()` function, you used `!=` for all comparisons. I think you should use `<` and `>` for index comparison.

I have debugged your code. Check it out.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void mark(int x, int y, char bd[][8]);  
void display(char bd[][8]);     
void init (char bd[][8]);       

int main()
{
    char b[8][8];       
    int r,c;        //variable to store row and column
    init (b);       //initially marking every position with '*'
    cout << "Enter the posotion of the queen:" << endl;
    cout << "Row: ";
    cin >> r;
    cout << "Column: ";
    cin >> c;
    mark(r,c,b);        //function to mark the attackable places
    display(b);         //function to display the output
    cin.get();           
}

void mark(int x, int y, char bd[][8])
{
    bd[x][y] = 'x';     //marking queen's position
    int i,j;

    //marking vertical line. '-' represent a attackable position 
    for (i=0; i<8; i++)
    {
        if(i != x)      
            bd[i][y] = '-';     
    }
    //marking horizontal line
    for (j=0; j<8; j++)
    {
        if(j != y)
            bd[x][j] = '-';     
    }

    //forward diagonal
    i = x+1;
    j = y+1;
    while(i < 8 && j < 8)
    {
        bd[i][j] = '-';
        i++;
        j++;
    }

    i = x-1;
    j = y-1;
    while(i > -1 && j > -1)
    {
        bd[i][j] = '-';
        i--;
        j--;
    }

    //backward diagonal
    i = x+1;
    j = y-1;
    while(i < 8 && j > -1)
    {
        bd[i][j] = '-';
        i++;
        j--;
    }

    i = x-1;
    j = y+1;
    while(i > -1 && j < 8)
    {
        bd[i][j] = '-';
        i--;
        j++;
    }

    return;

}

void display(char bd[][8])
{
    for(int i=0; i<8; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<8; j++)
            cout << bd[i][j];
        cout << endl;
    }
}

void init (char bd[][8])
{
    for(int i=0; i<8; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<8; j++)
            bd[i][j] = '*';
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are correct, the array value is never properly checked and thus the memory leak.